# Long time to fail connection to socket (C++/CLI .NET)

Tags: .net, sockets, c++-cli

I'm trying to connect to a socket when I start my app by using this method:

```
sck_client->Client_Connect(Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDownPort->Value),ip,sck_client->sck);
```

Which is defined as:

```
public: void Client_Connect( int Port, IPAddress^ ipAddress, Socket^  %sender) {

        try {
            IPEndPoint^ remoteEP = gcnew IPEndPoint(ipAddress,Port);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            sender = gcnew Socket(AddressFamily::InterNetwork, SocketType::Stream, ProtocolType::Tcp );

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try {
                sender->Connect(remoteEP);
                //MessageBox::Show("Socket connected to " + Convert::ToString(sender->RemoteEndPoint), "OPC_Socket_CC", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
            } catch (ArgumentNullException^ ane) {
                MessageBox::Show("ArgumentNullException : " + ane->Message, "OPC_Socket_CC", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
            } catch (SocketException^ se) {
                MessageBox::Show("SocketException : " + se->Message, "OPC_Socket_CC", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
            } catch (Exception^ e) {
                MessageBox::Show("Unexpected exception : " +  e->Message, "OPC_Socket_CC", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
            }
     } catch (Exception^ e) {
           MessageBox::Show(e->Message, "Socket_CC", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
        }
    }
```

But if the combination ip+port is not a valid direction on my net, it blocks the program about 15 seconds.

By the first time the user launches the application, IP and port have default values, so it's possible to have an incorrect endpoint address. How can I modify the connection timeout?

NOTE: It's not an option to use async connections.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The TCP/IP connection timeout can only be extended, it cannot be reduced.  Consider to Ping first.

Comment: I've used:

`IAsyncResult^ result = sender->BeginConnect(ipAddress,Port,nullptr,nullptr);
    bool success = result->AsyncWaitHandle->WaitOne(timeout,true);

    if(!success){
     sender->Close();
    }`

instead of `sender->Connect(remoteEP);` apparently working! :)